# 2 HTC Vive in a single Unity Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

I have ordered a HTC Vive and waiting to get delivered, Until then i am doing some R&D around how to set it up, how to run Examples, How to Interact etc.... I have below doubts and i didnt get any documents on this either, here they are,

```
1. Can we use 2 HTC Vive Headsets in a single Unity3d Scene
2. Can we use 2 HTC Vive as server & Client.
```

i have 2 systems on the same LAN and both systems have SteamVR Installed and Logged in with same User ID so whenever i start both the systems, both of them detects SteamVR in the network and show a pop up, so if they can detect over the lan then their should be something that can make multiple HTC Vive work in the same scene.

Share your experiences please.

Regards,
Jithendra.

Comment: It is possible as far as you make your scene/game a multiplayer I am currently working on a multiplayer game for htc vive  doing same and its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible when you set up the scene as multiplayer.

I was able to do this with little to no complication using [Proton](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/initial-setup), which is free on the unity store.

You can call `PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom()` &`PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom()` which has multiple callbacks for success and failure.

Then you are able to Instantiate another player over the network using `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate()`.

It's very well documented and easier to use in my opinion than the built in `UnityEngine.Networking` API.

As for your second question about server and client, Photon will automatically make the client that created the room the "master", which can be validated using `PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient()`.

Hope this helps,

Liam